# Text rendering: resizing text to fit inside a box?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text-rendering

I'm working on a text rendering system and I'm trying to implement a mechanism for automatically scaling down the text size to fit inside a specified box.

With word wrapping disabled, the task is nice and simple. All I have to do is check whether the width or height is proportionally larger, then scale the text down by that same ratio.

Unfortunately, with word wrapping enabled, the task gets much more complicated. If the text is larger than the box and I scale it down, the smaller text size might be able to fit more words onto each line, which might change the overall bounding box so that a different scale makes it fit the box better. Then applying that different scale might again mean there's a better way to word wrap it, and so on.

Most of the other solutions I've been able to find are basically:

```
while (isTooBig) { DecrementFontSize(); }
```

That would work, but could be very inefficient, so I was wondering if anyone knows of any lower level algorithms that deal directly with the text parsing? Failing that, do you know of any open source programs which include this feature so I can get their source code and see how they do it?

Edit: I'm doing this in Unity3D, but that doesn't really have any bearing on my problem since I'm implementing my own text rendering system.

Comment: Why do you think your suggested solution is 'very inefficient'?

Comment: @THBBFT because its a brute force method rather than an algorithm that can actively work towards its goal.

Comment: Fair enough, I would have used the word 'inelegant', but I see you point.  Is the size of the textbox changing continuously?  Are there many textboxes being rendered at the same time?  Have you prototyped the `isTooBig` property to determine the level of inefficiency?

Comment: Probably not, probably not, and no. My current setup would need some substantial modifications to get an iterative solution working, so I'm looking into the possibility of finding a smart solution first.